# jQuery input opacity change on hover, focus and val

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to have an input field which is set at opacity:0.8; fade to 1.0 if the mouse is over the input field as well as if the input is in focus and if there is data in the input.

If any of the above condition aren't true, then have the input fade back to 0.8.

I've used the focus function with a mixture of mouseover/mouseout and change function which verifies the val() of the input but I can't get the desired effect.

Anyone can help?

**HTML**

```
<form id="ajax-contact-form" class="contactForm">
    <label>Simply type your email.</label>
        <input class="textbox" name="email" type="text" value="">
        <input class="sendMessage" name="submit" value="Send Email" type="submit">
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
    .contactForm .textbox {
    width: 564px;
    height: 46px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #182A76;
    outline: 0;
    border: 0;
    background: url('../images/form.png') left 97% no-repeat;
    opacity:0.8;
    filter:alpha(opacity=80)
    }
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input.textbox").mouseover(function() {
    $('.textbox').fadeTo("slow", 1);
}).mouseout(function() {
    $('.textbox').fadeTo("slow", 0.8);
})

if($("input.textbox").val() === "") {
    $('.textbox').css({ opacity: 0.8});
} else {
    $('.textbox').css({ opacity: 1});

}

$('input.textbox').focus(function() {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo("slow", 1);
    }).blur(function() {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo("slow", 0.8);
    });
```

});

Comment: Post what you have tried so far.. share the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kKKbh/)

```
$("input")
    .on("mouseover focus",  function() { 
        $(this).animate({ opacity: 1 }); 
    })
    .on("mouseleave blur", function() {
        if ( $(this).val() == '' && !$(this).is(":focus") ) {
            $(this).animate({ opacity: .4 });
        }
    });
```